# Can I have have terms with the same slug in the same taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I am populating my database directly from another database and I do have some hierarchies like:

A > B > **C**

and

D > **C** > E.

This means that I do have the same terms, in the same taxonomies in different hierarchy levels (with different parents in term_taxonomy_table).

Taxonomy archive now gets posts from all terms with the same name...
Is there any way to make taxonomy template work properly with this setup?

If so, which filter(s) can I use to handle this by myself?

Thanks.

Comment: In short - no. WordPress is built to handle unique terms, and when you have multiples named the same thing - even if they're not in the same taxonomy - it is easily confused about what you're requesting. Perhaps you could clarify why you're populating directly from another database, yet using different hierarchies, so we could suggest other options?

Comment: I am using WooCommerce and the hierarchy items are the product's categories, as `Luggage` > `backpacks` > `acessories` and `Kitchen` > `accessories` > `forks`

Comment: Since slugs have to be unique within given taxonomy, I don't see how you could have the same `accessories` slug in different branches of your categories tree.

Comment: just tried this (needs improvements), but it seems to work: https://pastebin.com/tkKSMGeL

Comment: Using `pre_get_posts`...
I am basically forcing a tax_query *by slug* for a tax_query *by term_id*. Is this idea valid or will it break somehow?